# Поиск в списке внутри списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список вида `[[10, 3], [20, 1], [11, 4], ...]`
Можно ли так сформулировать поиск, чтобы искать входит ли искомое число (например 12) во внутренние списки на первой позиции. То есть нет ли числа 12 среди ряда `10, 20, 11 ...` и в случае, если входит, то получить индекс вида `list[][]`?

Comment: можно конечно, почему нет

Comment: Похоже я не доформулировал вопрос. А если можно, то как?

Comment: тут скорее не хватает попыток и вашего кода, с формулировками все ясно

Comment: В настоящее время я разделяю их на два списка и ищу в прямом (. Я только изучаю язык.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l=[[12, 3], [20, 12], [12, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Находим индекс листа, содержащего 12 и индекс в этом листе:

```
>>> [(n,x.index(12)) for n,x in enumerate(l) if 12 in x]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 0)]
```

Находим индексы листов, в которых первый элемент 12:

```
>>> [n for n,x in enumerate(l) if x[:1]==[12]]
[0, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
collection_of_numbers = [[12, 3], [20, 1], [12, 4]]

for index, list_of_numbers in enumerate(collection_of_numbers):
    if 12 == list_of_numbers[0]:
        print('list[{0:d}][0]'.format(index))

indecec = [index for (index, list_of_numbers) in enumerate(collection_of_numbers) if list_of_numbers[0] == 12]
for index in indecec:
    print('list[{0:d}][0]'.format(index))
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать, есть ли `12` на первой позиции во вложенных списках:

```
>>> pairs = [[10, 3], [20, 1], [11, 4], [12, 4]]
>>> any(x == 12 for x, *_ in pairs)
True
```

Чтобы найти индекс пары cо значением `12` на первой позиции:

```
>>> next(i for i, (x, _) in enumerate(pairs) if x == 12)
3
```

Чтобы найти все индексы пар из списка, у которых на первой позиции `12`:

```
>>> [i for i, (x, _) in enumerate(pairs) if x == 12]
[3]
```

Comment: В задаче требуется получить индекс (или в общем случае - индексы), а не просто проверить наличие или отсутствие заданного числа на заданной позиции.

Comment: Вариант с next(...)  в представленном виде находит только первое вхождение 12 в список. Для того, что-бы эту идею ( с next) довести до работающего состояния - надо явно создать итератор (ф-цией iter), а затем циклом с next вытянуть все индексы. Как по мне - сложновато.

Comment: @passant в вопросе "индекс" или "индексы" по вашему написано?

Comment: Вообще-то в программировании принято писать либо "найти первое вхождение", и тогда достаточно того, что написано, либо -  если это не указано явно - рассматривать все возможные случаи, а именно: ноль вхождений, одно вхождение, много вхождений. Разве не так? Впрочем, если мы говорим о школьных задачах и подходах - может это и излишне, но прививать соответствующие навыки даже школьникам - все-же не помешает.

Comment: @passant в русском языке слово "индекс" означает *единственное* число. Мы можем ожидать что и ребёнок различает *один* и больше одного.

Comment: для ясности: в программировании (и не только): "найти X" и "найти все возможные X" -- это разные задачи. Не стоит их путать. К примеру, "найти путь до  города" и "найти все возможные пути до города" -- это разные задачи (поэтому `find()` и `findall()` отдельно обычно существуют).

Answer (score 0):

```
# определяем как первый индекс так и все остальные (если надо)  

lst = [[12, 3], [20, 12], [12, 4], [3, 4], [124, 6], [12, 43]]  # имеем список списков  
res = []  
for i in lst:  
    res += i  # объединяем списки в один список  
# res=[12, 3, 20, 12, 12, 4, 3, 4, 124, 6, 12, 43]  

for n, x in enumerate(res[::2]):  # используем список res от 0 с шагом 2  
    if x == 12:  
        print(n, x)  
# Результат:  
# 0 12  
# 2 12  
# 5 12
```